# Cannot submit a model with Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make an update form for ApplicationUsers on MVC.

This is my controller:

```
   // Usuarios/Modificar
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Modificar")]
    public ActionResult Modificar(ApplicationUser modifiedUser)
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));

            var applicationUser = userManager.FindById(modifiedUser.Id);

            if (applicationUser != null)
            {
                applicationUser.Apellido = modifiedUser.Apellido;
                applicationUser.Nombre = modifiedUser.Nombre;
                applicationUser.Dni = modifiedUser.Dni;
                applicationUser.Interno = modifiedUser.Interno;
                applicationUser.Email = modifiedUser.Email;
                applicationUser.UserName = modifiedUser.UserName;

                userManager.Update(applicationUser);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

And this is my View:

```
@model Core.Models.ApplicationUser

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Modificar", "Usuarios", new AjaxOptions(){ HttpMethod = "POST", }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="box box-default">

            <!-- #region Header del Box -->
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Usuario: @Model.UserName</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- #endregion -->

            <!-- #region Cuerpo del box. -->
            <div class="box-body">
                <!-- #region Fila 1. -->
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- Columna 1. -->
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> <label>Apellido: </label>
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Apellido, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Apellido, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col -->
                    <!-- Columna 2. -->
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> <label>Nombre: </label>
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nombre, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nombre, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col -->
                    <!-- Columna 3. -->
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> <label>Documento: </label>
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dni, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dni, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col -->
                    <!-- Columna 4. -->
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> <label>Mail: </label>
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col -->
                    <!-- Columna 5. -->
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> <label>Usuario: </label>
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col -->
                </div>
                <!-- #endregion /.row -->

            </div>
            <!-- #endregion /.box-body -->

            <div class="box-footer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1 pull-right">

                        <input type="submit" name="btnAppUser" id="btnAppUser" class="btn btn-default pull-right" value="Guardar" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
</div>
}
```

But, after submit, when the post reachs the controller the applicationUser is empty. The Ajax form is not sending the info or it's not binding into the ApplicationUser model. Can anyone help me understand the problem here?

Thanks!

Comment: Your bound model elements need to be inside the ajax form.

Comment: @RyanWilson sorry, I didnt get that. Can u explain a little more?

Comment: Have you added 
`<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>` key in app settings of web.config file and reference of `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` javascript ?

Comment: @RyanWilson actually I formatted the code a bit and I think they are already in the right place.

Comment: @ADyson Ok. Thank you for formatting it. I guess that wasn't the problem then.

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution yes. unobtructive ajax works well in most cases but this.